# Wrapping a torus with a spiral

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create the effect similar to hula hoop covered in tape using three.js.

The 3d model should end up looking something like below.

[image: Taped Hula Hoop]

I can create the hoop in 3d space using `TorusGeometry` with the ability to pan around, but I have not managed to work out how to get a 2nd `TorusGeometry` to break into sections.

What is the best way of creating this effect?

```
// hoop
hoop = new THREE.TorusGeometry(20, .5, 100, 50);
var hoopMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    ambient: 0xffffff,
    color: 0x028fde,
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 0
});
hoopMesh = new THREE.Mesh(hoop, hoopMaterial);
hoopMesh.position.z = 0;
scene.add(hoopMesh);

hoopTape1 = new THREE.TorusGeometry(20.1, .6, 0, 50);
var hoopTapeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    ambient: 0xffffff,
    color: 0xDE5102,
    specular: 0x555555,
    shininess: 0
});
hoopTape1Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(hoopTape1, hoopTapeMaterial);
hoopMesh.position.z = 0;
scene.add(hoopTape1Mesh);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3listone/0555Lt3f/) with current working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to apply a texture to your torus that is *seamless* to achieve that effect. The texture should be similar to this one:

[image]

Then use this code pattern:

```
var geometry = new THREE.TorusBufferGeometry( 6, 0.4, 16, 64 );

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = loader.load( 'stripe.jpg', function ( texture ) {
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set( 16, 0.5 ); // or whatever you like
    render();
} );

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0x998877, 
    specular: 0x050505,
    shininess: 50,
    map: texture
} );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.77

Comment: Is there anyway to make the black part of the texture transparent e.g. allowing the first torus show in the gaps?

Comment: I worked it out! I used exactly the same texture as above but replaced the black with alpha layers.

Comment: For fun, do this: Use the original texture with `alphaMap: texture, alphaTest: 0.5, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true`.

Comment: Compare `texture.repeat.set( 16, 0.25 );` vs `texture.repeat.set( 16, 0.5 );`